# Error Message In WCF REST POST Service

Tags: c#, wcf

Is it possible to return an error message for POST method ?
For GET method , i used `WebFaultException` to return an error message.

Here is my client code to consume POST Service:

```
try
            {
                BudgetTransactionRequest bt = new BudgetTransactionRequest
                {
                    transaction_code = "MHSS112",
                    category = "Expenses",
                    amount = 12345,
                    claim_status = "Propose Re-Class",
                    application_type = "test saja",
                    request_date = new DateTime(2013, 03, 09),
                    request_status = "Validated",
                    owner = "nurul.widiyanti", 
                };
                WebClient proxy = new WebClient();
                proxy.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                DataContractJsonSerializer serialize = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(BudgetTransactionRequest));
                serialize.WriteObject(ms, bt);
                byte[] data = proxy.UploadData("http://localhost:1910/Service1.svc/CreateBudgetTransaction/MLPT03", "POST", ms.ToArray());
                Stream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
                DataContractJsonSerializer obj = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(BudgetTransactionRequest));
                Console.WriteLine("Success !!");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR : " + ex);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
```

There is an owner string which contain name of the user. When i fill with wrong user name. It will return bad request. Meanwhile, in server code. I placed try catch block to return an exception if some of field is wrong. Nah, i want the client can get the exception from server code. Is it possible ?

Comment: 'user not found' isn't a bad request.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh: I don't know, but that what i get when i inpute wrong username. Is there a way to return an error message like using `WebFaultException`